# Creating a symlink with sudo in Capistrano 3.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I am deploying my Rails app with Capistrano 3. I've struggled all the way through, but now when everything is almost done I cannot create a symlink through a Capistrano task.

With Capistrano 2.x I could easily do it with the following line:

```
sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/#{application}"
```

Now Capistrano 3 has advocated `passwordless sudo` approach as described [here](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/authentication-and-authorisation/#toc_8).

I've added the following line to `sudoers`

```
deployer ALL=NOPASSWD:/etc/init.d/sites-enabled/application-name
```

and changed my command in Capistrano task to:

```
execute :sudo, :ln, "-nfs", "#{current_path}/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/#{fetch(:application)}"
```

What am I missing? Is the line I added to `sudoers` correct?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alex, when you edit `sudoers`, you should list commands you would like to execute (not the files you'd like to symlink).

Thus, the line in `sudoers` should be as follows:

```
deployer ALL=NOPASSWD:/bin/ln -nfs /current/path/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/application-name
```

You can also make it more general:

```
deployer ALL=NOPASSWD:/bin/ln -nfs /current/path/* /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*
```

but it will be less secure.